# CountingSort with ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, collections, counting-sort

I'm trying to implement the Counting Sort algorithm with an `ArrayList` but I have some difficulties.

I in this piece of code I want to calculate the occurrence of each element in the `ArrayList` named `l`.

*My code:*

```
List<Integer> l = // initializing the given list

/** initialize the occurrence of each element in the count array **/

List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>(max-min+1);

for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){
    
    //count[arr[i]-min]++;

    int index = l.get(i) - min; //ok
    int value = 0;
    value = value++;
    count.set(index, value);
}
```

I can't find out how to perform the increment.

Comment: What is `count`? Is it a `HashSet`? (I guess do because below you are doing `count.set(...)`). You cannot index into a `HashSet` with `[...]`.

Comment: Hi, count is List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>(max-min+1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a parameterized constructor of `ArrayList` which allows providing a *capacity* you're still getting an **empty** `ArrayList`. The difference is that it would have an underlying array of the desired size instead of the default size of `10`.

But you still have no elements to access. In order to populate `ArrayList` with default values, you can use another parameterized constructor that allows to provide a collection.

To create a light-weight auxiliary list of size `max - min + 1` filled with zero integers (which would be passed to the constructor) you can use the utility method [`Collections.nCopies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)):

```
List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(0, max - min + 1));

for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    int index = l.get(i) - min;
            
    int value = count.get(index);
    count.set(index, value + 1);
}
```

**Note** that implementing Counting sort by using `ArrayList` instead of a plane array, frankly saying, isn't very convenient. If it's an assignment requirement or self-imposed challenge - make sure that you understand how to implement the algorithm using arrays.

Comment: I update the code, but I want the occurrence of each element in the array count

Comment: @Alessandro See the updated code in the answer.

Comment: @Alessandro Also, please get familiar with the guide-lines on how to ask questions [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide your question with *minimal* but at the same time *sufficient* amount of code that allow to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to increment a primitive numerical variable, say, `value`.
`value++` is one of them, additionally resulting in the value of `value` *before* the increment.
I'd have to read up whether the sequence between incrementing `value` and assigning to value in `value = value++` is defined -
sanity advises to avoid it.
I use the increment operator where I intend *next*,
and `value += 1` where I intend *increase by 1*.
(The other shortest one is `++value`… yielding the value after increment.)

When incrementing the value in a `List<Integer> values` at a given index `i`, there are two possibilities:
either explicitly `get()` and `set()`, relying on auto-(un)boxing like [Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784984) suggests,
or use a *mutable Integer* - [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) has `set(newValue)`, `getAndIncrement()` and `incrementAndGet()`.